# Finding out exact time from HTML <time> tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently scraping some data using BeautifulSoup and ran into issues regarding the time element found on webpage html.

In the url below, you will find a list of discussion posts, each detailed with a title, author's name, and time of posting relative to the current local time. The source code shows the text which the page is displaying, but I can't seem to find any datetime attribute to refer to for the exact date of each post.

If you go to page 4 in the list, you will find that once a month has passed from the posting date, the post will start displaying its exact posting date, instead of its "relative time". Is there any way I can retrieve the exact date for the postings that display their "relative time"?

URL: https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Tablets/bd-p/get-help-tablets

Comment: Short answer is no, you will need to calculate the time.

Comment: If the data you want is not present in the HTML you're scraping, you won't be able to scrape that info, no.

Comment: I've analyzed the source code and jon p is right, the exact date isn't present on the source code, you'll have to calculate it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow a link to an individual post you will find that the relative timestamp has a title attribute showing the exact time:

```
<span title="‎07-22-2019 01:50 PM" class="local-friendly-date">6 hours ago</span>
```

you could scrape that title text. It's going to take a little more recursion (and of course the posts that already have an exact time don't have that HTML), but there should be some logic to achieve what you want once you figure out what a "local friendly" date is.